# Aggregate query with document containing array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am facing issue with the aggregation query on MongoDB.

I have a document in following structure:

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("19a5070b808028108101"),
    "arr_vs": [
    {
        "arr_id": "one",
        "val": 5
    },
    {
        "arr_id": "two",
        "val": 5
    }]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("19a5070b80802810810"),
    "arr_vs": [
    {
        "arr_id": "one",
        "val": 5
    },
    {
        "arr_id": "two",
        "val": 2
    },{
        "arr_id": "three",
        "val": 1
    }]
}]
```

I want the count for each value associated with arr_vs items.

Expected output:

```
{
    "arr_vs":{
        "one":[
            {
                "val":5,
                "total_count":2
            },{
                "val":2,
                "total_count":
            }
        }],
        "two":[
            {
                "val":5,
                "total_count":2
            },{
                "val":2,
                "total_count":
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outputting to named keys is never really the fantastic thing some people seem to think it is. Realistically I usually want to work with the results returned, and therefore a "list/array" makes a lot more sense.

This is basically every new person basically gets told to abandon their "named keys" concepts, and realize they are working with a database and the inherent problems with named keys. Kind of also why collections are essentially "lists" as well.

So you would be better off getting used to the concept:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$arr_vs" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "id": "$arr_vs.arr_id", "val": "$arr_vs.val" },
    "total_count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.id",
    "v": {
      "$push": { 
        "val": "$_id.val", 
        "total_count": "$total_count"
      }
    }  
  }}
])
```

Which is basically going to give you:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "two",
    "v" : [ 
        {
            "val" : 2.0,
            "total_count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "val" : 5.0,
            "total_count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "one",
    "v" : [ 
        {
            "val" : 5.0,
            "total_count" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "three",
    "v" : [ 
        {
            "val" : 1.0,
            "total_count" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

And is the aggregated data in an iterable and easy to use form.

If you are intent on your output format and have at least a MongoDB 3.4.4 version, you can take that further by compacting the documents and using [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$arr_vs" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "id": "$arr_vs.arr_id", "val": "$arr_vs.val" },
    "total_count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.id",
    "v": {
      "$push": { 
        "val": "$_id.val", 
        "total_count": "$total_count"
      }
    }  
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "arr_vs": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": "$v"    
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "arr_vs": { "$arrayToObject": "$arr_vs" } 
  }}   
])
```

Or even just apply the final "reshape" client side, if your MongoDB version does not support the new operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$arr_vs" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "id": "$arr_vs.arr_id", "val": "$arr_vs.val" },
    "total_count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.id",
    "v": {
      "$push": { 
        "val": "$_id.val", 
        "total_count": "$total_count"
      }
    }  
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "arr_vs": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": "$v"    
      }
    }
  }},
  /*
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "arr_vs": { "$arrayToObject": "$arr_vs" } 
  }}
  */   
]).map( d => ({
  "arr_vs": d.arr_vs.reduce((acc,curr) =>
    Object.assign(acc,({ [curr.k]: curr.v })),{})    
}))
```

And both produce the same output:

```
    {
        "arr_vs" : {
            "two" : [ 
                {
                    "val" : 2.0,
                    "total_count" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "val" : 5.0,
                    "total_count" : 1.0
                }
            ],
            "one" : [ 
                {
                    "val" : 5.0,
                    "total_count" : 2.0
                }
            ],
            "three" : [ 
                {
                    "val" : 1.0,
                    "total_count" : 1.0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```